# QGIS symbology to SLD for web map

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, openlayers, sld, vector-tiles

I use **OpenLayers together with QGIS Server** to deploy GIS projects as WMS service online and everything works fine using it together with MapProxy for seeding and caching layers.

Now I want to substitute some graphically really simple raster layers by vector tiles and render them client side. I tried different approaches, but none of them works out perfectly as complex symbology and expressions are [not totally convertible](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/23356).

My workflow is basically to select vector layers as WFS in QGIS Server settings and export styles for this layers with a python parser. On Openlayers side I use WFS from QGIS Server and apply the SLD with [SLDReader](https://github.com/NieuwlandGeo/SLDReader).

I tried with SLD and QML, but both have the limitation that expressions are ignored:

1. To write **SLD** from QGIS I use [saveSldStyle](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsMapLayer.html?highlight=qgsmaplayer#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.saveSldStyle).
2. To convert **QML** to SLD I use [Geostyler](https://geostyler.org/).

So should I code a translation of my expressions and to appropriate SLD code, or is there a different solution I didn't think of. Any Thoughts?

Basically I have really simple expressions to change size of symbols depending on map scale, something like:

```
CASE 
WHEN @map_scale < 1500 
THEN  8
WHEN @map_scale >= 1500 and  @map_scale < 3500 
THEN 6
ELSE 4
END
```

This then should be converted to scale based symbology with SLD using `<MinScaleDenominator>` and `<MaxScaleDenominator>`.